# Snake Game Artificial Intelligence

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I am developing a snake game for iOS:
https://github.com/ScottBouloutian/Snake

My goal is to have the AI complete the game of snake optimally (have the snake fill the board).

I am using IDA* to find a path from a snake's current location to the food. This works. However, the algorithm doesn't take into account the fact that it may need to get more food in the future. As a result, sometimes it tends to box itself in.

i.e. The snake's goal at any given time is to find the food, whereas it's goal should be to fill the board (finding food along the way).

How can I add to or modify this approach to make the AI win the game of snake? Is there a better approach I should use instead? I'm just trying to come up with some ideas. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds to me like a good approach.  The trick with A* though is to choose a good heuristic.  You need to think about how to choose a heuristic that gives you the behavior you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

If a board is a static rectangle (not torus - so no crossing though the borders) then the only optimal strategy is to find a **set of longest closed paths** through the board, such that each point in the board is in at least one path.

If a board is empty (there are no obstacles) then there exists an "ultimate" path in the form

```
 16|.1|.6|.7
 15|.2|.5|.8
 14|.3|.4|.9
 13|12|11|10
```

which goes through all tiles, snake following this pattern will eventually eat all food, and fill the whole board

If there are some obstacles, then such path does not have to exist, then you should find set of such longest paths, and switch between them, when food appears in the unreachable spot of a current path.

For example

```
#######
#.....#
#.#.#.#
#.....#
#######
```

Here you have two paths you have to consider, one-longest, going around the whole board, but missing the central spot, and one small loop going through it. As long as food does not appear in the center, you should use the outer loop. Hopefully, if food appears in the center when you fill all the remaining blocks - you will "win". If it appears there sooner - you have to eat it (switch to the other loop) and depending on your current length - you will get back to the best loop, or hit your tail and "lose". In each case, your score will be the best possible to achieve on the board with this locations of foods.

**Non A*** based approach will find the optimum, this is completely different problem, you should look for the **longest closed** path, not **shortest**.